# Can someone explain the difference between django's gzip packages

Tags: django, gzip

It seems like they have a gzip_page decorator for views

```
from django.views.decorators.gzip import gzip_page

@gzip_page
def viewFunc(request):
   return HttpResponse("hello"*100)
```

Reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/decorators/#module-django.views.decorators.gzip

as well as a middleware class you can add to settings and then use.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
 django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware,
 ...

)
```

---

```
from django.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware
gzip_middleware = GZipMiddleware()
def dec(request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return gzip_middleware.process_response(request, response)
    return dec
```

---

Using the page decorator kind of sped up the rendering of a huge ammt. of data (for a table), was wondering which way was best/ what the differences were.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in [Django sources](https://github.com/Empeeric/dirometer/blob/master/django/views/decorators/gzip.py), you will see that `gzip_page` decorator and `GZipMiddleware` are in fact one and the same thing:

```
gzip_page = decorator_from_middleware(GZipMiddleware)
```

So there is no difference at all (apart from some overhead needed to convert middleware to decorator). If you need to enable gzip only for one specific view you should obviously use the decorator, but if you want to have gzip on for the entire project, use the middleware.

As a sidenote, I'm sure you will get much better performance if you leave gzipping to whatever web server you are using (Apache, nginx, etc.)

Also be aware that you shouldn't use gzip for HTTPS protected websites, more on it here: http://breachattack.com/

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I had read that it is better to let the server gzip, but have discovered through (a small sample of trials) that gzip is faster than my local server. I guess a real production server would be faster though. Either way, we are using HTTPS, so I won't use django's package - I was completely unaware that gzipping was a concern for HTTPS.

Comment: @amchugh89 gzip should not be used with HTTPS at all (unless you really know what you're doing). Even if it is done by webserver.

Comment: Do you know how to check if webserver is compressing? I'm not the 'server guy,' but I'd like to share this information with him

Comment: @amchugh89 http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/curl-tip-check-that-the-apache-compression-gzip-deflate-is-working/ for example